# Populating java list in front end

Tags: java, collections

Suppose, we are fetching year lists [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012] from database. Now my requirement is to show these years in a dropdown dynamically fetching from the database. But, the problem is- I am keeping these years into a java list. While running this query
**Select distinct years from schema_name.table_name order by years desc with ur;**
It is giving the expected result in DB, but while taking this query in java code then it is behaving like-
[2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2013, 2012]. Are there any mistakes from my end? Or I have to change the java collection?

N.B: I am using DB2.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you [edit] the question and add a [MRE]?

Comment: Perhaps try the query without the `WITH UR`. It well known to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information? Maybe because your're using a non-indexed List with hibernate ,which will be treated as a Bag semantics,which doesn't preserve order of the elements.